# Recommended Structure for Twilio Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controller, twilio

What is the best structure for this Twilio project?

Phone numbers are POSTed and stored to be dialed at a later time (to be triggered by cron)

I have a controller to accept incoming POST requests and add the numbers to the database.
I also have a rake task (called via CRON) that pulls all the numbers that need to be dialed.

Where should I place the method for making the actual call? Right now I have it in a controller, would it be better to have it as a module or a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a controller to handle the twilio api calls, but my model contains the methods to actually send the calls.

Answer (score 3):

If someone feels like they need an example, I'd suggest you check out the Twilio tutorials. Full disclosure: I work for Twilio.

In the [automated survey Rails example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/automated-survey/ruby/rails), we demonstrate a call flow using `<Say>`, `<Record>`, and `<Gather>` TwiML verbs. And we show you how to maintain conversation state in a database that spans multiple webhook requests.

Hopefully seeing how we've structured our app will help you get started  on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in a model or a lib.

Could it be part of the model that the number is stored in? A Number#dial method perhaps?

Comment: Making the call is just one of the methods related to handling calls. There are also methods for handling voicemail and user responses. I figured it would be best to have a separate container for all those methods, rather than sticking them all into the Customers controller that handles the incoming POST (number import) requests.